# Update multiple radio buttons based on select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I'm trying to update a series of radio button in a sharepoint 2013 custom new form, based on a select option. My code so far:

```
function setTierDestinations(destination) {
    var radios = $("#DeltaPlaceHolderMain").find("span[title='" + destination + "']:first-child");
    console.log(radios);
    $.each(radios, function(i, value) {
        $(value).prop("checked",true);
    });
}

document.getElementByID(ctl00_ctl43_g_f596e023_21bc_42e0_b68b_c8a7b74467a3_ff151_ctl00_DropDownChoice).onchange = function () {
    var destination = document.getElementByID(ctl00_ctl43_g_f596e023_21bc_42e0_b68b_c8a7b74467a3_ff151_ctl00_DropDownChoice).value;
    setTierDestinations(destination);
};

<select name="ctl00$ctl43$g_f596e023_21bc_42e0_b68b_c8a7b74467a3$ff151$ctl00$DropDownChoice" id="ctl00_ctl43_g_f596e023_21bc_42e0_b68b_c8a7b74467a3_ff151_ctl00_DropDownChoice" title="Destination" class="ms-RadioText">
    <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
    <option value="Store">Store</option>
    <option value="Shed">Shed</option>
</select>

<span id="radioA"><span dir="none">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span class="ms-RadioText" title="Store">
                    <input id="ctl00_ctl43_g_f596e023_21bc_42e0_b68b_c8a7b74467a3_ff271_ctl00_ctl00" type="radio" name="ctl00$ctl43$g_f596e023_21bc_42e0_b68b_c8a7b74467a3$ff271$ctl00$RadioButtons" value="ctl00" checked="checked" /><label for="ctl00_ctl43_g_f596e023_21bc_42e0_b68b_c8a7b74467a3_ff271_ctl00_ctl00">Store</label>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span class="ms-RadioText" title="Shed">
                    <input id="ctl00_ctl43_g_f596e023_21bc_42e0_b68b_c8a7b74467a3_ff271_ctl00_ctl01" type="radio" name="ctl00$ctl43$g_f596e023_21bc_42e0_b68b_c8a7b74467a3$ff271$ctl00$RadioButtons" value="ctl01" /><label for="ctl00_ctl43_g_f596e023_21bc_42e0_b68b_c8a7b74467a3_ff271_ctl00_ctl01">Shed</label>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</span></span>
```

All the content in #radioA gets duplicated several times as #radioB, #radioC, etc.

I think I'm not selecting the radios var properly. In console I'm getting an array of multiple "span.ms-RadioText" where I should be getting inputs. Is this the correct usage of first-child?

Comment: Do you want to select all 2 radio buttons when user select an option from the SELECT ?

Comment: Yes, I would need to select 9 copies of the input tag in the relevant `<span class="ms-RadioText" title="Store">` where the title is a variable based on the select option.

Comment: You should replace  `getElementByID` by `getElementById` and the id should be string so use it between double qoutes `"`.

Comment: Hi Zakaria, Thanks for the comment. The `getElementByID` is just selecting the value of the select option. The select only appears once. It's that value that need to be passed to the radio's.

Comment: Totally unrelated . But i quit my previous job because they asked me to do sharepoint :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of first-child isn't selecting the children of your target element. You want .children()
This should work
    var radios = $("#DeltaPlaceHolderMain").find("span[title='" + destination + "']").children()[0];

Which will select the first child of the span.

The :first-child selector doesn't select the first child of the element, but the element that matches the selector that is the first child of the parent.
http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/:first-child

To reiterate and elaborate on what Zakaria said, 
getElementByID is written incorrectly. It should be `document.getElementById` 
Note the lowercase d.

Your id should be in quotes, as it is a string, and not a variable. So `document.getElementById('ctl00_ctl43_g_f596e023_21bc_42e0_b68b_c8a7b74467a3_ff151_ctl00_DropDownChoice').onchange` etc.

Comment: Thanks Andy and Zakaria. This was just a typo when typing it up here. I've double checked my `document.getElementById` by logging it out to the console and I have the correct values "Store" or "Shed". The issue I have is definitely within the `setTierDestinations` function.

Comment: Edited the answer to add a way to select the first child of the span elements.

Comment: Thanks Andy, that's what I was missing. The final function that worked was this: `function setTierDestinations(destination) {
  var radios = $("#DeltaPlaceHolderMain").find("span[title='" + destination + "']").children();
  $.each(radios, function(i, value) {
   $(this).prop("checked",true);});}`